# Data is not being saved as Encrypted data django

Tags: django, encryption, django-rest-framework

till now I tried more then 6 plugins and quite frustrate now. Now using  this one  [cryprtography](https://pypi.org/project/django-cryptography/)

everything is fine and done accordingly but when I save data in model manager like this

```
 def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.test_field = 'new.user@oc.com'
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

it saving data normally not encrypted

My model is like

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    test_field = encrypt(models.CharField(max_length=100))
    objects = UserManager()
```

Comment: How do you know the data is not encrypted ? django-cryptography encrypt the data seemlessly, are you sure you check data directly in your DBMS and not through Django ?

Comment: I am checking data in django-admin panel and its showing same static data @Blusky

Comment: It's normal. Django Admin will display decrypted the content from DBMS.

Comment: @Blusky alright got my mistake . :( all plugins were working fine. Now If I want this data in my web so It should automatically in readable form ?

Comment: Yes. Those plugin are just meant to be protected from the database. Once used in django, it's used as if it were clear (except for search filters and other ORM magic stuff)

Comment: @Blusky  and I can't lookup on this and search etc ? because I can't right now

Comment: Yes, you can't query on encrypted field, that's one drawback. Fields are decrypted as the ORM treat DBMS data, not on SQL query.

Comment: @Blusky is there any work around or anything I can do about it ?

Comment: You could always fliter in Python after the ORM converted DBMS data, but you'll lose all SQL power. If you encrypt the data, it's because you don't want the data stored in cleartext, if the data is not stored in cleartext, the DMBS cannot treat it locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are doing everything as expected.

Data should be encrypted on the Database end.

However, it's normal to see the data in clear text on Django side because the ORM decrypt it seamlessly.

If you check the data directly on the database (using raw SQL query without an ORM), you should see encrypted data.

If you need to filter encrypted data, you should do it in python, after ORM decryption :

Instead of doing `User.objects.filter(test_field__contains="somedata")`, you will need to do `[user for user in User.objects.all() if "somedata" in user.test_field]`. The (big) drawback of this method is that you will need to pass all rows into the ORM (and decryption mecanism)

Comment: kindly can you please give small example how I can filter on that data ? it would be great favor .